# How could Demons, Merfolk and Angels evolve?

Tags: science-based, society, creature-design, evolution, mythical-creatures

I am writing a prospective scenario for a satirical horror-comedy and science-fantasy Web-series for adolescents (or teenagers if you want) and adults where humans cohabit with demons, merfolk, and angels.

Some basic characteristic of my demons include:

- Are eusocial like naked-mole rats: there are five castes (from lowest to highest): the workers, the artists, the businesspeople, the soldiers, and the royal couple (only one female and one male that can reproduce);
- Are omnivores with carnivorous tendencies like ravens;
- Are mostly scavengers but occasionally act as ambush predators (when they consume other animals);
- Are fossorials like moles;
- Have an excellent sense of smell, of hearing, of taste, and of touch, but a relatively poor sense of eyesight;
- The royal couple is monogamous;
- Workers are the smallest: they weigh on average only a kilogram (2.2 pounds), artists weigh on average 10 kilograms, businesspeople weigh on average 50 kilograms (110 pounds) soldiers weigh on average 100 kilograms (220 pounds), the king weighs on average 125 kilograms (275 pounds), and the queen weighs on average a tonne (one metric ton) (1000 kilograms) (or 2200 pounds if you want);
- Workers can live 60 years, artists can live 120 years, businesspeople can live 180 years, soldiers and the king can live 240 years and the queen can live three centuries (30 decades) (or 300 years if you want).

Some basic characteristic of my merfolk include:

- Are as solitary as blue whales;
- Are obligate omnivores like brown rats;
- Are mostly pursuit predators but occasionally act as scavengers (when they consume other animals);
- Have an excellent sense of hearing, of eyesight, and of touch, but a relatively poor sense of taste, and smell;
- They are the size of an adult beluga, females are 25% heavier than males, but males are 10% longer (in other words, females are more massive in terms of volume and mass, but males are larger in terms of length);
- They can be found in all Earth's oceans, but they prefer temperate and subtropical zones (like Gaspé Peninsula/Gaspesia, and New York Harbor).

Some basic characteristic of my angels include:

- Are as social as male cheetahs;
- Are omnivores with herbivorous tendencies like American black bears;
- Are mostly ambush predators but occasionally act as pursuit predators (when they consume other animals);
- Have an excellent sense of eyesight, of taste, and of hearing, but a relatively poor sense of smell, and touch;
- Have a wingspan as wide as the wandering albatross;
- Their wings are their hands like bats;
- When they are on the ground, they walk bipedally in a similar way to a pigeon;
- Males are 10% taller and slightly more voluminous than females, but females are 5% heavier (females weigh on average 8 kilograms, and males are on average 1.25 metres tall).

Demons, merfolk, and angels are all lukewarm-blooded like tunas and great white sharks. They have human-level intelligence. Finally, they have the same skin colour range as humans, the same eyes colour range as humans, and (except in merfolk: they have a glabrous skin like a dolphin) the same hair colour range as humans.

Given these characteristic, what respective species could they have evolved from, and what evolutionary pressures would lead to them?

Note 1: except for demonic possession and angelic hypnosis, magic does not exist in my world.
Note 2: the Abrahamic God and Satan do not exist in my world.
Note 3: like humans, my demons, my merfolk, and my angels can be of any morality and ethics.
Note 4: there are also ogres: [What evolutionary pressures would lead to Ogres?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/192977/what-evolutionary-pressures-would-lead-to-ogres)

Comment: It takes some doing see how your demons evolved at all.  I mean, they have one reproductive couple and the queen lives 300 years.  Additionally, the castes are *hardwired* to social roles in somewhat civilized societies, with 'artists' and 'businessmen' being specialized only to some sorts of thinking.  Given the long history of post-sentient evolution that implies, I would want to suggest an artificial evolutionary path for these.

Comment: Your final question " what respective species could they have evolved from?" Does not match your title question. And what is a fossorial?

Comment: Voted to close : One question at a time :). Even if the question is the same among all species, it might or might not be answered the same way with the same results. It also closes people's mind as they'll try to find a common ancestor, while you don't seem to find it important (what "respective" species...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### They are Humans

It seems like your various species are supposed to be human-like. If that is so, then the only possibility is that these species share a similar ancestry to humans. Specifically, they would have to come from the *Homo* genus, or at least the hominid family